# "bundle: command not found" when trying to commit with SmartGit. How do I update my bundle path in SmartGit?

Tags: git, smartgit

My team has added some pre-commit hooks that require bundler to be installed. Now when I try to commit on SmartGit I'm getting this error:

`Commit: commit failed (return code 1); gems out of date! Running bundle install. This may take a moment. /preCommitScriptFile: bundle: command not found`

I'm using SmartGit, and I think it's something specific to that. How do I tell my SmartGit GUI where to find `bundle`?

Comment: Can you successfully commit from command line? Also try to use the same Git which is used by SmartGit (see Preferences, Executables).

Comment: I can commit from command line...and it turns out I have git in /usr/local/bin/git AND /urs/bin/git from a recent git update....but when I updated the SmartGit executables to be the newer one I recently updated in /usr/local/bin/git it still has that same probably finding `bundle`